# Unexpected Blank lines in python output

Tags: python, file, csv

I have a bit of code that runs through a dictionary and outputs the values from it in a CSV format.  Strangely I'm getting a couple of blank lines where all the output of all of the dictionary entries is blank.  I've read the code and can't understand has anything except lines with commas can be output.  The blank line should have values in it, so extra \n is not the cause. Can anyone advise why I'd be getting blank lines?  Other times I run the missing line appears.

Missing line:

```
6415, 6469, -4.60, clerical, 2, ,,,joe,030193027org,joelj,030155640dup
```

Using python 2.6.5

Bit of code:

```
      tfile = file(path, 'w')
      tfile.write('Rec_ID_A, Rec_ID_B, Weight, Assigned, Run, By, On, Comment\n')
      rec_num_a = 0

      while (rec_num_a <= max_rec_num_a):
        try:
            value = self.dict['DA'+str(rec_num_a)]
        except:
            value = [0,0,0,'rejected']
        if (value[3]!='rejected'):
            weightValue = "%0.2f" % value[2]
            line = value[0][1:] + ', ' + value[1][1:] + ', ' + weightValue \
                             + ', ' + str(value[3]) + ', ' + str(value[4]) 
            if (len(value)>5):
                line = line + ', ' + value[5] + ',' + value[6] + ',' + value[7]
            (a_pkey, b_pkey) = self.derive_pkeys(value)
            line = line + a_pkey + b_pkey
             tfile.write( line + '\n')
        rec_num_a +=1
```

Sample output

```
6388, 2187, 76.50, clerical, 1, ,,,cameron,030187639org,cameron,030187639org
6398, 2103, 70.79, clerical, 1, ,,,caleb,030189225org,caldb,030189225dup
6402, 2205, 1.64, clerical, 2, ,,,jenna,030190334org,cameron,020305169dup
6409, 7892, 79.09, clerical, 1, ,,,liam,030191863org,liam,030191863org

6416, 11519, 79.09, clerical, 1, ,,,thomas,030193156org,thomas,030193156org
6417, 8854, 6.10, clerical, 2, ,,,ruby,030193713org,mia,020160397org
6421, 2864, -0.84, clerical, 2, ,,,kristin,030194394org,connou,020023478dup
6423, 413, 75.63, clerical, 1, ,,,adrian,030194795org,adriah,030194795dup
```

Comment: first learn to use the built in string formatting functions, http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Comment: @fuzzy: those are going away in Python 3.0, and anyway if you're going to pick on something, I would say iteration style ;-) Martlark, this is a perfect place for `for rec_num_a in xrange(max_rec_num_a)`

Comment: Am I using the string formatting wrong?  I'm not using the built in csv module because this is not my code.

Comment: The iteration is not optimized but I'm fairly sure it does not make any difference to if records are output as blank lines.

Comment: @fuzzy, @David, you can still use `str.format()`, with placeholders. Definitely better than a bunch of concatenation.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, and use csv. Especially if you're not yet good enough to debug your wheel when it falls off :)

Comment: poor code is poor code regardless of "whos code it is" fix it and make it better with the solutions listed here.

Comment: He isn't using 3.0 he is using 2.6.5 and that is good advice for that version. My advice to avoid string concatenation it is difficult to maintain and debug is still valid.

Comment: What I'm doing is trying to put together a test suite so I can compare the outputs of the code I've been given against improvements I make.  Part of this is checking the output files and this output module removes one line for no reason I can see.  What I wanted to find out if something in python number/string formatting could cause a line to not format correctly.  I'll try .strip() just to make exclude that.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you not using Python's built-in [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module?

Then, what does `self.derive_pkeys(value)` do? Could it be that `b_pkey` sometimes ends with `\n`?

Answer (score 1):

without seeing the source data it is hard to tell, but I could speculate that your data has some stray `\n` characters in it, like in `b_pkey` . You could try and do a .strip() on that value to make sure it is clean.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Please say precisely what a "blank line" is -- contains only a newline? contains one or more spaces? Other whitespace characters?

(2) How did you determine the answer to Q1? ["looked at in a text editor" is not a good answer, nor is "printed it to my terminal and eyeballed it"; try `print repr(line)`]

(3) How have you determined that the "missing data" is actually in the input dictionary?

(4) Some runs work, some don't ... so what else is different? From what is the dict populated? A multiuser database? A static file?